# how to select a contact with keyboard on skype?

Tags: skype

When trying to talk to a contact on my skype, i normally have to click on the contact with mouse for it to pop up, whist if the focus is on contact list, you can simple type the first letter of the skype name to get to that contact, is there a keyboard to set focus on the contact if the current focus is somehwere else?

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom keyboard shortcuts as shown in

https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12025/what-are-hotkeys-and-how-to-use-them

Go to Tools > Options...
Click the Advanced tab and select Hotkeys.

There you'll find an option to "Search for people on Skype"

Set the desired hotkey for that action.

Comment: this is not exactly the option am looking for, i am looking to set focus in the search bar right on top of the contact list-people are my friends, not strangers with potential i can send my request to.

Answer (score 0):

Use ALT+1 or ALT+2 to select Contacts or Recent tab. This also focuses the contact list.
Hit ENTER to select contact or conversation, which focuses typing field in conversation.